# While loop not updating variable defined by user

Tags: java

So, I have two classes.
main class:

```
package guiprojj;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import guiprojj.gui;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Test {
    public static String movie;
    public static String line;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader rd;
        OutputStreamWriter wr;
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter input:");
        //movie = s.nextLine();
        //movie = movie.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        while (movie != null)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=" + movie);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.flush();

                // Get the response
                rd = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                line = rd.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                } else {

                    System.out.println("Sorry! That's not a valid URL.");
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException codeyellow) {
                System.err.println("Caught UnknownHostException: " + codeyellow.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Caught IOException:" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

gui class:

```
package guiprojj;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class gui {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame maingui = new JFrame("Gui");
        JPanel pangui = new JPanel();
        JButton enter = new JButton("Enter");
        JLabel movieinfo = new JLabel(Test.line);
        final JTextField movietext = new JTextField(16);
        maingui.add(pangui);
        pangui.add(movietext);
        pangui.add(enter);
        pangui.add (movieinfo);
        maingui.setVisible(true);
        maingui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        maingui.pack();
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  
            {
                Test.movie = movietext.getText();
                System.out.println(Test.movie);

            }
            });
        }
}
```

What I am writing is a program that outputs the movie data from imbd after you enter it in the box, and I am running into an issue.
When I type in the movie, and press enter, it still shows as null and doesn't seem to be outputting the data from the api I am using.

Comment: you have 2 main methods, are running in different procces?

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.  It will help you solve issues like this.  Both now, and for the remainder of your career as a programmer.

Comment: How do you run it? Which `.class`?

Comment: yes. **Debugger.**  step through your code, to see what *is* happening, not what you *think* is happening.

Comment: Please elaborate on "*it still shows as null*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    public static String getMovieInfo(String movie) {
        BufferedReader rd;
        OutputStreamWriter wr;
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println("Enter input:");
        //movie = s.nextLine();
        //movie = movie.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        if (movie != null)
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=" + movie);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.flush();

                // Get the response
                rd = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String line = rd.readLine();
                if (line != null) {
                   return line;
                } else {

                    return "Sorry! That's not a valid URL.";
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException codeyellow) {
                System.err.println("Caught UnknownHostException: " + codeyellow.getMessage());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Caught IOException:" + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return "passed parameter is null!";
        }

        return "an error occured, see console!";
    }
}
```

I've rewritten your Test-class. Renamed main-method, added return-statements (String) and removed the while-loop. Try to avoid multiple main(String[] args)-methods in one project, else your IDE could launch the "wrong" one, if your context switches.
I did not test it, but now you should be able to call Test.getMovieInfo("movie-name") from your gui-class to get the info.
(nethertheless this code should be refactored ;))

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It seems to now not ever run, I've been trying to figure out the error, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. It seems to now not ever run, I've been trying to figure out the error, but I can't seem to find it.Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 movie cannot be resolved or is not a field
 movie cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I removed the `movie` and the `line` fields from your Test-class, because I did not need them anymore after my changes.

Comment: just change your `Test.movie = movietext.getText(); System.out.println(Test.movie);` to `System.out.println(Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText()));`

Comment: Now I'm getting: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

Comment: Also,
JLabel movieinfo = new JLabel("info:" + Test.getMovieInfo(movietext.getText())); doesn't work, for some odd reason.

Comment: Whats the odd reason?

Comment: By the way, all the errors look like runtime errors, but normally they should occur on compile time. How do you compile your code? Do you use some kind of IDE?